# How can I get an 'undefined control sequence \begin{thebibliography}{1}'?

Tags: bibtex

I am trying to add a bibliography to my document. I create a test.tex:

```
\documentclass[twocolumn, a4paper]{ieicejsp}
\bibliographystyle{plain}
\begin{document}

Cite\cite{GDE3}
\bibliography{bibliography}

\end{document}
```

I run the `bibtex` command and get a

```
test.aux=>text.bbl 
Done!
```

Then I try to run the `LaTeX` and get an error:

```
'undefined control sequence \begin{thebibliography}{1}'
```

But the contents of `text.bbl` file are:

```
\begin{thebibliography}{1}

\bibitem{GDE3}
Saku Kukkonen and Jouni Lampinen.
\newblock Gde3: the third evolution step of generalized differential evolution.
\newblock In {\em IEEE Congress on Evolutionary Computation}, pages 443--450,
  2005.

\end{thebibliography}
```

Please, what am i missing?

EDIT1:

The exact error message was:

```
This is pTeXk, Version 3.141592-p3.1.11 (euc) (Web2C 7.5.4)
 %&-line parsing enabled.
(./test.tex
pLaTeX2e &lt;2006/11/10&gt;+0 (based on LaTeX2e &lt;2009/09/24&gt; patch level 0)
(./ieicejsp.cls
Document Class: ieicejsp 
) (./test.aux) (./test.bbl
! Undefined control sequence.
&lt;argument&gt; \refname 
                    \@mkboth {\refname }{\refname }
l.1 \begin{thebibliography}{1}
```

EDIT2:

As Joseph Wright suggested, adding

```
\newcommand*{\refname}{Bibliography}
```

just before the

```
\begin{document}
```

command solved the problem. Thank you! You have no idea how much you helped me.

Comment: Please provide a link to the class file `ieicejsp.cls` you use. Not even the [IEICE's Author's Guide](http://www.ieice.org/ftp/tex/ieice/LaTeX2e/) provides this file...

Comment: Actually ieicejsp is a mystery to me. I got it from a friend. I just have to use it for a conference. It is dreadfuly long http://pastebin.com/D8tBUEK9

Comment: [`ieicejsp.cls`](http://pastebin.com/D8tBUEK9) *does* provide a `thebibliography` environment (see lines 705-722), so I don't know why there could be a problem; it is definitely "supported."

Comment: Thank you for your effort. I really appreciate that you dove into the monstrous document for me. Now the strangest thing happened. Even though there is an error, a file with the correct bibliography was generated! All of a sudden

Comment: @MartinDrozdik Could you copy-paste the exact error you see? I get and error about `\refname` being undefined, which does seem to be the case looking through the class. That means its more-or-less broken, but doing `\newcommand*{\refname}{Bibliography}` should fix that.

Comment: @JosephWright It works! I have yet to grock TeX to understand why, but it does! Thank you!

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Maybe your ieicejsp doesn't support this? I tried your file with report and it worked (after doing multiple runs with pdflatex, so it could resolve the dependencies).

Note: Had to use another template, because I don't have ieicejsp installed.

Comment: Thank you! It may be the case. I will ask the person who gave it to me in a few days, accept the answer and post the solution

Answer (score 8):

The error indicates that `\refname` is being used by the class but is not defined. That is a bug in the class file: `\refname` is not defined by the LaTeX kernel, so any class using it should define it. It can be fixed by adding

```
\newcommand*{\refname}{Bibliography}
```

after the `\documentclass` line in your document, but really I would be suspicious of a class with such an obvious error.

Comment: Shouldn't `\usepackage[english]{babel}` help too?

Comment: @tohecz It would, but I'd still say that the class is out-and-out defective.

Answer (score 1):

Based on [previous answer](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/66742/230830), for `IEEEtran.cls` commenting `\section*{References}` and replace it with `\newcommand*{\refname}{References}` solve the problem.

```tex
% \section*{References}
\newcommand*{\refname}{References}

\begin{thebibliography}{00}
```